# Using Microsoft word fonts in latex

Tags: typography, font-encodings, copy-paste

I have a document written in Microsoft Word where the following languages were used: 
Greek, Coptic and Hebrew in addition to Arabic and Hieroglyph languages as well as Syriac.

I used Unicode fonts to write the document, such fonts include:
Coptic: FreeSerifAvvaShenouda - Antinoou
Greek: Palatino linotype
Syrian: Setro Jerusalim
arabic: Simplified Arabic
Hebrew: Ezra SIL

I need a way to convert the document to LaTeX without re-writing the body text.

The issue is to re-write the text written in Coptic language as well as Hieroglph and syrian. Is there a way to convert a MS-fonts to latex fonts.

"So the main issue is how to use MS-unicode/non-unicode fonts in altex - HOw to convert a MS word document to LAtex without re-writing the body text"

Find attached a sample of the text used[image]

Comment: welcome to TX.sx. What have you tried so far?

Comment: if you use xetex, you can use system fonts.  then, it depends on how the fonts are arranged; if everything is in unicode order, or with a unicode identifier, the probability increases.  but really, more information is needed.  if you can provide a small example file with, say, one typical sentence in each language, there's a good chance that someone here can help.

Comment: Why do you want to convert the document exactly? It seems strange to spend years getting a document just to your liking only to decide to convert it into another format. That process will inevitably require a good deal of work in order to get things into a format you're happy with, even in the best case scenario of a maximally smooth transition.

Comment: If the Word file is saved as .docx, it's XML, and can be transformed to LaTeX with an XSLT2 program. You would need to make yourself intimately familiar with the markup with which Word represents your Greek, Coptic, Hebrew, Arabic, and Hieroglyph material (that means studying the Word XML) and I have no idea if your hard work has been represented consistently in Word. But it is certainly possible.

Comment: I am new to latex, I have been using word yet my document became about 1000 pages. I am using the Master document option in word yet they say that it may cause the files to corrupt sometimes. That is the reason I am trying to learn latex since they say it is very efficient with large documents.and yields better results than word.

Comment: You have a lot of work to do: every time you switch languages, you’d want to wrap the text in something like `\foreignlanguage{greek}{Αβγδε}` for short interpolations, or `\begin{otherlanguage}{syriac}` for longer passages. All your formatting would have been lost, so you’d need to add commands like `\textbf` wherever they’re needed. You also need to mark up the structure of your document, by writing `\chapter{Title of the Chapter}` and so on where appropriate. Optionally, you can set up your PDF file’s metadata in `hyperref` and add anchors to your sections, etc.

Comment: You need to set up your preamble and compile with XeLaTex. (The experimental HarfTeX might also work.) You want to load `\usepackage[bidi=default]{babel}`, since it’s a bidirectional document. You would then load each language with a command like `\babelprovide[import]{hebrew}`. Set up a series of font substitutions like `\babelfont[greek]{rm}[Ligatures={Common, Rare}]{Palatino Linotype}`, `\babelfont[hebrew]{rm}{Ezra SIL}`, etc. You might find it useful to declare `\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchUppercase}` first.

Comment: Having done that, you can select the entire text of your document, copy, and paste it into your LaTeX source after `\begin{document}`.  This wipes all your formatting. In theory, there are document converters that input docx and output tex, but I’m not aware of any that work well enough to save you the trouble of going through the whole text and marking it all up by hand. Sorry!

Comment: My apologies for having to answer in the comments.

Comment: If anyone wants to take a shot at a converter that parses the docx file, [here is the spec for the OpenOffice format.](https://www.openoffice.org/xml/general.html)